# How to eliminate excess clickable area on image link?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I have a triangluar image like so:

[image: logo png file]

It is a png file.

I access it using html like so:

```
<a href="/link"><img src="/logo.png" alt="alternate"></a>
```

How do I ensure that the only clickable area of the image is the black area and not the clear/white part?

Comment: you can't.. unless using image maps or canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image maps will do that for you: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Great, never knew about this!